# How to map leaflet heat-map layer points with tile-layer points

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've non-map images like floor images.

By using Leaflet image-Overlay I load these images, And with the help of Leaflet-heat plugin I generate heat-map layer on that image.

But heat-map positions and coordinates of image are mismatched.

please help me to solve this problem.

My Output image:[My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk7t2.png)

Black dots in yellow box of the image are the points where i have to generate the heat-map.

I mentioned the coordinates of these points below.

```js
var imgDimensions={width:1713, height:1625};
var map = L.map('map',{
 maxZoom: 0,
 minZoom: 0,
 crs:L.CRS.Simple
}).setView([imgDimensions.height/2, imgDimensions.width/2],0);

var imageUrl = "D:/Jithu/LeafLet/images/Floor1.png";
var imageBounds = [
 [imgDimensions.width , 0],
 [0, imgDimensions.height]
];

L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);

addressPoints = addressPoints.map(function (p) {
 var contPoint = map.layerPointToContainerPoint(L.point(p[0],p[1]));
 var latlong = map.layerPointToLatLng(layerPoint);
 return [latlong.lat,latlong.lng,p[2]]; 
});

var heat = L.heatLayer(addressPoints, {
 minOpacity:0.0,
 max:1.0,
 radius: 10,
 gradient:{
  0.4: 'blue', 
  0.65: 'lime',
  1: 'red'
 }
}).addTo(map);

// addressPoints.js
//[X-cord, Y-cord, Intensity]
var addressPoints = [
  [637, 383, 1],
  [724, 397, 0.5],
  [682, 444, 0.5],
  [714, 515, 1],
  [589, 500, 1]
];
```

```html
<div id="map" style="width: 1713px;height: 1625px"></div>
```

Comment: How does your heatmap look like right now? What is the content of `addressPoints`?

Comment: Hi @IvanSanchez addressPoints contains the coordinates of image and intensity vlue

Comment: Can you add one or two such points to your example?

Comment: i am unable to add the picture of my output. those address points are the coordinates  of points in the image

Comment: i also have to use this. did you find any solution??